# What is the IP address for connecting Android project to WampServer?

Tags: java, android, mysql, wampserver

I am writing an Android (Java) project that connect to MySQL database on wampserver on my Windows machine. But I don't know what IP address I should use to connect to my local wampserver?

Comment: Open command prompt and type `ipconfig` that'll return an IP address of your system. Check for `Wireless LAN Adapter : IPv4` address. Use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If is on your local machine it will most likely be localhost.

On your web browser:

```
localhost
```

Should bring your wamp homepage, or go to the wamp application and launch phpMyAdmin to make sure your database is online.